# Rails. Save parent, before save children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try create line_item, I get this error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (You cannot call create unless the parent is saved).

When I wrong? How fix it?

line_items controller

```
def create
  @product = Product.find_by_id(params[:line_item][:product_id])
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(line_item_params)
end
```

cart model

```
has_many   :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(line_item_args)
    current_line_item.quantity += line_item_args[:quantity].to_i
    current_line_item.save

  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += line_item.quantity.to_i
  else
    current_item = line_items.create!(line_item_args)
  end
  current_item
end
```

**UPD**

working helper method current_cart from application controller. problem was in it.

```
def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
end
```

Comment: save/create cart first?!?

Comment: I try add after_save :add_product in cart model, but error is persists

Comment: after_save :add_product won't fix that. Probably, @cart is not persisted. You must create/save cart before creating any associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how you are working with the cart but i'm amoust sure current cart is not persited on de database, check if its true.

Comment: problem was in my helper method current_cart. thanks for help.